# How to install PDO Sqlite on windows?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

Does anyone know how can I install PDO SQLite extension on Windows?

I have PHP 5.3 compiled with the following config:

```
Configure Command => cscript /nologo configure.js  "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--disable-zts" "--disable-isapi" "--disable-nsapi" "--without-mssql" "--without-pdo-mssql" "--without-pi3web" "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-11g=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient11\sdk,shared" "--with-enchant=shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--disable-static-analyze"
```

Comment: Doesn't 5.3 come with SQLite as standard? Have you run phpInfo(); in your 'index.php' web page and you should see what version it has? [Windows stuff is explained here](http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.installation.php).

Comment: No it does not. Documentation on php.net is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason my PHP was not shipped with sqlite DLLs so I downloaded archieve from here: http://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/

Then copied php_sqlite3.dll and php_pdo_sqlite.dll to my PHP extensions dir and enabled it in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that if you use it on Windows that some `php_pdo_sqlite.dll` versions come with a dependancy on `msvcrt90.dll` (or other versions).
So the dependancy walker would show if it is installed quickly.